# Dynamically add/hide tabpanel in viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs

This code is executed when clicking on menu item:

```
var objectTabPanel = Ext.create('App.view.ObjectTabPanel');
var tab = Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').add(objectTabPanel);
```

But if I click on the menu item again, the tabpanel is created again.
How to create a condition? If the tabpanel is created and opened, then switch to it. If the tabpanel is not created and is not open, then create and switch to it.

I want the behavior such as, for example, in SublimeText:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ext.getCmp('componentID').show()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-show):

```
...
onObjectsClick: function(item, e, eOpts) {
    if(!Ext.getCmp('objectsPanel')) {
        var objectsPanel = Ext.create('AMS.view.ObjectsPanel');
        Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').add(objectsPanel);
    }

    Ext.getCmp('objectsPanel').show();
},
...
```